# upgrading/installing webpack gives An unknown git error occurred

Tags: webpack, upgrade

I'm stuck,
I'm trying to upgrade webpack.
I first upgraded node.js,
I've tried to find a solution online, uninstalling, calling different things in different order like:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm -g uninstall webpack
```

running as admin.
I'm calling these things from Visual Code terminal

But I'm stuck, I get the following errors:

```
>>npm install webpack
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/null/^3.1.0.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```